Pandas : How do I drop all rows in a data frame that does not meet a condition?
I have a huge dataframe, and the "date" column represents the year&month, for example, December of 2022 would be 202212. I want to drop all rows BESIDE rows that represents the end of the year, thus rows that consists of a year+12, for example, a row with 202012. I would like to keep.
How do I drop all rows that does not have a year+12 in there "date" column?
Since my data is only between 1999-2022. I tried to do:
list =[199912,200012,200112,200212,200312,200412,200512,200612,200712,200812,200912,201012,201112,201212,201312,201412,201512,201612,201712,201812,201912,202012,202112,202212]
    
    df2 = df.drop(df[df['date'] not in list].index)

It returns:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Anyone can help?

Sidenote: don't call a variable list. You are overwriting the built-in function list.

Plenty of ways you could do this, here is an example using endswith for string columns, and mod division if it's an integer.  Alternatively you could convert it to a date object and reference the month.
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['a','b','c'], 'date':[200010, 200011, 200012]})
# If string
df = df.loc[df['date'].astype(str).str.endswith('12')]
# If integer
df = df.loc[df['date'].mod(100).eq(12)]
# Using date objects
df = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m').dt.month.eq(12)]

